# How do I get the value in a sessionScope variable within an appendItemValue call

Tags: xpages

I created a sessionScope variable that hold a list of field names and another set that are made up of those field names and the values that are stored in them.

allFieldNames is the scope variable that contains all the field name

allFieldNames
[0] T0Q1
[1] T0Q2
[2] T1Q1
[3] T2Q1
[4] T3Q1
[5] T4aQ1
[6] T5Q1
[7] T6Q1
[8] T7Q1

SS Value
T0Q1 As a part of an acquiring/purchasing/merging with another company.
T0Q2 Yes
T1Q1 Strongly agree
T2Q1 Agree
T3Q1 I have an extensive active network of experts and resources.
T4aQ1 I sometimes require assistance
T5Q1 None of these.
T6Q1 To a reasonable extent
T7Q1 Agree

```
var questions = @List(sessionScope.allFieldNames);
for( i=1; i < sessionScope.ssTotalQuestions; i++ ) {
    viewScope.put("x", @Subset(@Subset(questions,i),-1));
    newDoc.appendItemValue(x, viewScope.x);
}
```

The appendItemValue does create the field as I wanted but the problem I am having is that I cannot get the values in the matching scope variable. I know it is **viewScope.x** in my code that is causing the problem, but I cannot figure out how to identify and reference the scope variable at this point.

FYI, there is no back end form to grab these field names from - this form is created on the fly, all fields are created on the form through this routine and it is then saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
for( i=1; i < sessionScope.ssTotalQuestions; i++ ) {
    newDoc.replaceItemValue(sessionScope.allFieldNames[i], sessionScope.ssTotalQuestions[i]);
}
```

(If the field-name is part of your data, you might need to use indexOf(" ") to find the first blank). However it is a bit fragile... you have name/value pairs here, so you might want to replace your two scope variables with one HashMap, so you can be sure you never run out of fields for your questions. Something like:

```
viewScope.questions = new java.util.HashMap();
viewScope.questions.put("T0Q1","As a part of an acquiring/purchasing/merging with another company.");
...
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That won't work since sessionScope.ssTotalQuestions[i]); is just the total number of questions and does not contain anything related to the field names. Sorry if that wasn't clear. Might have to investigate hashmaps if I cannot get this to work.

Comment: could you add sample content of ssTotalQuestions? And yes, I'll bet HashMaps will save you the trouble

Comment: var totalQuestions = @Elements(@DbLookup(@DbName(), "xpProfileSurveys", sessionScope.ssSurveyName, 1));
sessionScope.put("ssTotalQuestions", totalQuestions)

Comment: so totalQuestions contain the questions you want to ask, how do you map them to the answer fields you want to store them in. If the sequence of your fieldnames matches the sequence of your questions, the array approach will work - but it is fragile. Smells like you are really better off with a Map. You could pull the questions like ID|Text and then loop through the @dbLookup result and use split()